# How to convert part of json respons to javascript date using angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON REST service that returns a list of periods with start dates. How can I convert the start date to javascript date?

```
  [ {
      "periodId": 1234, 
      "startDate": [ 2011, 12, 24]
    }, 
    {
      "periodId": 5678, 
      "startDate": [ 2012, 12, 24]
    }
   ]
```

I'm using ngResource in my service definition:

```
  angular.module('periodservice',['ngResource']).
     factory('Periods', function($resource) {
      return $resource('../rest/periods', {}, {
        query : {method : 'GET', params : {}, isArray : true}
      });
    });
```

The controller is pretty straight forward.

```
  function EksternVareRedigeringCtrl ($scope, Periods){

    $scope.periods = Periods.query(function(success, status, headers){
      $scope.msgf = success;
      console.log("this is the succsess);
    }, function(errors){
      $scope.msgf = errors;
      console.log("This is an error....." + ' ' + $scope.msgf.status);
    });

  }
```

Now I display the date like this instead of converting it to a proper date:

```
   <div class="period">Period: {{period[0]}}-{{period[1]}}-{{period[2]}}</div>
```

Comment: Is your 'startDate' in the format [year, day, month] ? ('2012,24,14' doesn't seem to be a valid date =) )

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. It's actually in this format [2012, 12, 24]. The examples have been update. :-)

Comment: Find a workaround by adding 

    $scope.periodDate = function(period){return new Date(period.startDate)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to Javascript Date:

```
new Date(period.startDate[0], period.startDate[1]-1, period.startDate[2])
```

Note that I've used `period.startDate[1]-1` because the months start at `0` (January) and end at `11` (December).

To process the dates only once, add the following snippet to your `success` callback:

```
angular.forEach($scope.periods, function (period) {
    period.startDate = new Date(period.startDate[0], period.startDate[1]-1, period.startDate[2]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly! 

Note. You do not have to subtract -1 from month number when supplying an array to new Date():

`code`
    new Date([2012, 12, 24]) === new Date(2012, 11, 24);
`code`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot. It works perfectly!

Note. You do not have to subtract -1 from month number when supplying an array to new Date():

```
 new Date([2012, 12, 24]) === new Date(2012, 11, 24);
```

Comment: The constructor new Date([2012, 12, 24]) does not work in IE8.